# how to hide private key using craco build for react in docker image on beanstalk

Tags: reactjs, docker, environment-variables, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am currently using craco and am using env-cmd to pass .env file into craco build as follows:

```
"build:nightly": "env-cmd -f .env.nightly craco build"
```

I am running the environment in a docker image.  However, the problem is I have to commit the .env file onto github which I don't want to because one of the variable in the .env file is a private key.  I am trying to figure out how to get craco to build by reading the host environment variables.  I am using Beanstalk and have set the environment variables in the configuration.  But my docker image is not picking that up.  Does anyone have any idea or recommendation on how I might be able to achieve this?

Thanks in advance